# Excel - #VALUE! error message

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting

I type $1000 in cell D31.  I type `=D31+50` in cell D32 because I want D32 to show $1050.  I then want to copy that formula into the next 100 cells in row D so that the value in each cell is $50 higher than the one before it.  This is a bookkeeping exercise, so I need each cell to have a dollar sign.

However, when I do this, I get the `#VALUE!` error and I can't figure out why.  I'm aware there are other ways to achieve this, but I need to know why *this particular way* isn't working.  Many thanks.

Edit:  I've added two screenshots to show more clearly what's happening.  This is what I type:

[image]

And this is what I get when I hit Enter or Tab:

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you are doing,,, I'm surprised that why U are getting error, please [edit] your post & share sample data with us , the screen shot !

Comment: try typing 1000 not $1000, and format the cells as currency

Comment: Hi @PeterH, even if OP type $1000 and D31+50 and drag in either direction ,, no error will appear will be $1050, $1100,,,, ! $1000 will be Currency not  text.

Comment: Are you sure @RajeshS ?

Comment: @PeterH,, yes you just try,, , keep format General, enter $1000, Excel will convert $1,000, add 50 and drag will $1,050. IF $1000 is Text , add 50,, get 1050,,,, !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing $1000 will be in the format of text, and you cannot add 50 to a text value. You need to format as a number value, in your case currency.
Select column D and change the format, see image below.

Or Row 30, whichever way you are doing your book.
Then type 1000 into D30 without the dollar sign, this will be added automatically, and in the next cell type =`D30+31` and drag.

[image]

You can also edit formats, by selecting a range of cells then right clicking and choosing number format to bring up all the options .

Comment: That's very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @PeterH even is TEXT $1000 , will never return #Value error but u get 1050, 1100 as Text !!

Comment: I tried it my end and got #Value error Rajesh